# Zend Framework 2 to create Doctrine entity of single table from database

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have configured doctrine ORM in my ZF2 project and create doctrine entity of whole database. Now, I have added one more table named dashboard_group in database. How can I create Doctrine entity for only this table.

I don't want to replace other created entities.

Comment: i didnt understand what you want exactly ? if you want to add new entity to your database with doctrine its better to first  write your entity in doctrine format and then use this command to update your database 
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
 .please make your question clear

Comment: I have a table in database and now I want to create Entity class in ZF2. I use the following command.

./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Company\\Entity\\" --force --from-database --filter="companies" annotation ./module/Company/src/

But it says "No Metadata Classes to process."